# What types of signals can a dynamic microphone generate?

Tags: transformer, differential, microphone, polarity, transformerless

And what design generates what type of signal property?

For example there are dynamic mics with or without output transformers. Do they differ in the type of signal outputted?

Do most dynamics generate a balanced differential signal where pin 3 is polarity reversed?

Also where and how is the pin 3 signal polarity inverted? At the voice coil? At the output transformer?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output transformer just changes the source impedance (And provides some voltage (but never power!) gain).

Most preamps load the mic with a couple of k ohms, so raising the impedance to a few hundred ohms or so if it is not there to start with helps system noise performance. This is particularly important in ribbon mics which have a notoriously low output impedance (a few tens of ohms or less) and low output voltage. A transformer that steps the impedance up by a factor of somewhere between 10 and 100 and the voltage by a factor of somewhere between say 3 and 10 (Impedance transformation is always the square of the voltage transformation in a transformer) is almost mandatory with these and often built in.

As to general types, there are really the usual pressure and velocity transducers the same as any other mic, plus the slightly odd ones like ribbons (Generally figure of eight), Variable D like the RE20 designed to cancel proximity effect, oddities like the Coles Lip Mics, and such. All of these could be made using condenser capsules, but the dynamic elements have the virtue of not needing tiny spacing and gigaohm impedance levels which matters where large level excursions and water vapour may be present.

Most mics (never mind dynamic or condenser) output a more or less balanced line, on some form of 3 pin connector, usually these days XLR, but Tuchel was once popular with older German mics and weirder things have been used.

Generally expect a few mV or so at a few hundred ohms source impedance, except for transformerless ribbons where you can drop those vales by a factor of 10 - 100 or so, a kick drum mic might be quite a bit hotter, but still generally peaking at less then 1V.

Comment: Ok so the transformer only changes the impedance and the gain. But i still don't understand if the mic outputs a differential signal.

Comment: Transformers can also convert single ended to balanced differential signals.

Comment: Most mics output a differential signal that is typically floating with respect to pin 1 which is just a connection for screening. This is different from most condensers where the phantom power requires that there be some connectivity between pin 1 and the signal lines (Generally a few k Ohms to each line), hey are typically still differential but have a lower common mode impedance in a condenser design.

Comment: Could you say that if a signal is floating it is automatically differential?

Comment: A floating signal pair is inherently differential (Actually ALL signals are differential in so far as voltages are measured as voltage differences) but possibly not balanced (which implies an equal impedance to some reference from both legs).

Comment: So a single ended signal is also differential?

Comment: Well to the extent that all voltages are measured as a difference between two points! This while true is uninteresting, what small signal analog usually means by differential is driven in antiphase, balanced and more or less floating with respect to some third shielding conductor. Most modern microphones meet this definition, with the exception of most laveliers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I'm still having trouble getting my head around this. I think maybe I'm missing some basic understanding of the difference between single ended and floating signals, why a ground is seen as fixed while the the other end of a voice coil is not seen as fixed. Why is there a difference? One is referenced to ground and one is floating. But what is the difference electrically? Both are circuits with current going out and returning. Sorry if this seems like a stupid question, really appreciate your help!

Comment: In a floating differential balanced configuration, which is the norm for a dynamic mic, neither end of the coil is connected to ground, they are just connected to pins 2,3 while the case of the mic is tied to pin 1. Ground is almost always a fiction, albeit a useful one on occasion. Pin one really serves to extend the metallic tube formed by the cable screen to surround the microphone element, and since low frequency electric fields do not penetrate metallic tubes well, this helps reduce the potential for noise pickup.

Comment: AES48 may be worth a read, and I think Bill Whitlock at Jensen transformers wrote a paper on this stuff as well. The Whitlock paper is good as it goes into some discussion of how balanced lines really work (It has NOTHING to do with driving the line with equal and opposite voltages!).

Comment: But why does the polarity of pin 3 get reversed? Is it something that happens in the voice coil? What is it that "drives them in antiphase"?

Comment: The microphone coil is in a magent structure forming a two terminal AC voltage generator, one terminal gets connected to each of pins 2 and 3, the impedance to pin 1 is very large. You actually use the thing my measuring the voltage between pin 2 and 3, if pin 2 is positive with respect to pin 3 at some instant then pin 3 is clearly negative with respect to pin 2, and a moment later this situation may be reversed as the vibration starts back the other way. Remember, Ground is a lie, sometimes we pick a common reference and refer to it as ground, but fundamentally all voltages are relative.

Comment: So a differential signal is less a lie than a grounded single ended signal? A differential signal is more in line with how physics would describe what is going on?

Comment: All voltages are measured between two points, and sometimes one of those points is connected to a mess of other things and it is convenient to call this ground, but yea, voltage is always relative to some other point. Note however that voltage is not the only thing we can measure! Line balance for example is defined by how equal the impedance from each of our signal lines is when measured to some third point (Conventionally the nearly mythical 'ground')..... End of the day, voltages are relative, and current flows in loops, all else (at low frequency) follows from that.

Comment: So even a single ended signal could be seen as driven with equal opposite voltages if we would ignore that the rest of the circuit is referenced to the minus side?

Comment: Yes, but the line balance would likely be very poor. Note that there is a trick, search for the term "Impedance balanced", it is a perfectly valid way to make a balanced line from a single ended source, providing the line balancing impedance is applied at the source end of the cable.

Comment: Yes, I've read something about that, alot cheaper then using a transformer for balancing!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers Dan, you are a very kind and helpful person!